# Simple task group class crashing

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future, promise

I am at wit's end with a simple task group class I wrote in C++11 and which is crashing in a heisenbug fashion (typically with a memory access error under heavy system load and - presumably - heavy thread scheduling pressure). First the code:

```
class task_group
{
    typedef std::promise<void> p_type;
    typedef std::future<void> f_type;
    typedef std::pair<p_type,f_type> pair_type;
    typedef std::forward_list<pair_type> container_type;
    template <typename Callable>
    struct task_wrapper
    {
        template <typename T>
        explicit task_wrapper(T &&c, pair_type &pair):m_c(std::forward<T>(c)),m_pair(pair)
        {
            m_pair.second = m_pair.first.get_future();
        }
        void operator()()
        {
            try {
                m_c();
                m_pair.first.set_value();
            } catch (...) {
                m_pair.first.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
        }
        Callable    m_c;
        pair_type   &m_pair;
    };
public:
    task_group() = default;
    ~task_group()
    {
        wait_all();
    }
    task_group(const task_group &) = delete;
    task_group(task_group &&) = delete;
    task_group &operator=(const task_group &) = delete;
    task_group &operator=(task_group &&) = delete;
    template <typename Callable>
    void add_task(Callable &&c)
    {
        m_container.emplace_front(p_type{},f_type{});
        task_wrapper<typename std::decay<Callable>::type> tw(std::forward<Callable>(c),m_container.front());
        std::thread thr(std::move(tw));
        thr.detach();
    }
    void wait_all()
    {
        std::for_each(m_container.begin(),m_container.end(),[this](pair_type &p) {
            if (p.second.valid()) {
                p.second.wait();
            }
        });
    }
    void get_all()
    {
        std::for_each(m_container.begin(),m_container.end(),[this](pair_type &p) {
            if (p.second.valid()) {
                p.second.get();
            }
        });
    }
private:
    container_type m_container;
};
```

Tasks (represented by a nullary callable object) can be added via the `add_task()` method, which launches the callable in a separate thread that gets immediately detached. The callable is actually wrapped in a wrapper structure that just takes care of setting the value of the promise once the callable has finished its work. Promises and futures are stored independently of the thread's lifetime in a persistent `forward_list`.

I am not doing anything funky with the class, just create it, add tasks and then wait for completion. A stupid example (from the unit test):

```
task_group tg;
std::vector<unsigned> values(100u);
for (auto i = 0u; i < 100u; ++i) {
    auto s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(1u);
    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW(tg.add_task([&values,s,i](){values[i] += boost::lexical_cast<unsigned>(s);}));
}
tg.wait_all();
BOOST_CHECK((std::all_of(values.begin(),values.end(),[](unsigned n){return n == 1u;})));
```

I have tried to run the test case through valgrind but all I seem to get are false positives regarding shared pointers reference counting. The class is so simple that I am convinced I am doing something really stupid, but a lot of googling about promises and futures did not hint at any major misuse on my side.

Comment: So are you calling `add_task`, `wait_all` and `get_all` from multiple different thread contexts under contention?  They are read/writing to `m_container` without synchronization.

Comment: Can you create a test program that heavily loads `task_group` and surfaces the crash consistently within a few seconds of starting?  What does your debugger say when such a test program crashes while running under it?

Comment: No, ``task_group`` objects are always accessed from the main thread. I am currently trying an alternative implementation that uses ``std::async`` and it has not crashed yet.

Comment: I have run the executable through valgrind but for some reason the bug is much harder to trigger there.

Comment: If you have a small test program that consistently crashes then post the full source of it to your post.  The more appropriate debugger to use if you are on linux is gdb.